# Labelling data based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I have a dataframe with several columns that looks like this:

```
id | x1 | text | x2 | num | x3 | class
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | 
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | # They don't all have the same vals
2nn| TT | word | QQ |  1  | TT | # This is just to illustrate it
```

I also have the following `lists` with strings:

```
class1 = ["",...]
class2 = ["",...]
class3 = ["",...]
class4 = ["",...]
class5 = ["",...] # Multiple strings, I just used '...' for simplicity
```

I am trying to assign classes in column `class` such that if the words in a transaction (row)'s `text` column contains any word found in any of the `lists`, assign the list name as the class.

I am doing this to label some data that I will eventually end up using for classification.

I want to perform this labelling only on data starting from row 10,000 onwards. What I'm using is:

```
# last 6000 rows
for index, row in df.tail(6000).iterrows():
    if df[df['text'].str.contains(class1)==True]:
        df.loc[row, 'class'] = "class1"

    if df[df['text'].str.contains(class2)==True]:
        df.loc[row, 'class'] = "class2"

    if df[df['text'].str.contains(class3)==True]:
        df.loc[row, 'class'] = "class3"

    if df[df['text'].str.contains(class4)==True]:
        df.loc[row, 'class'] = "class4"

    if df[df['text'].str.contains(class5)==True]:
        df.loc[row, 'class'] = "class5"
```

I am getting a response that prints the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Below is my code when trying Chris A's response:

```
# Word bins for the various labels
complaint = ["sucks", "worst", "doesn't", "didn't", "won't", "bad", "horrible", "unusable", "cannot", "can't", "not", "did not", "waste", "hate", "hated", "awful", "useless", "sucked", "freezing", "freezes", "froze", "does not", "crap", "stupid"]

compliment = ["awesome", "great", "amazing", "cool", "good", "nice", "nicest", "successful", "thanks", ":)", "successfully"]

neutral = ["Eh", "meh", "works"]

bug = ["please", "fix", "won't", "cannot", "can't", "not", "freezing", "freezes", "froze", "does not", "did not", "help", "plz"]

feature = ["it would be", "id like", "i'd like", "could", "can you", "implement", "feature", "lacks", "wish"]
def label_data(df):

    d = {'Compliment': compliment,
         'Complaint': complaint,
         'Neutral': neutral,
         'Bug': bug,
         'Feature': feature}

    for name, values in d.items():
        df.loc[df['review'].isin(values), 'label'] = name
```

My main class calls the data from a text file and then calls this method with the following:

```
df_orig = pd.read_table("PRIVATEPATH/data.txt", delimiter=",")
label_data(df_labelled)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be beneficial to use a python `dictionary` of your lists for this.

When using `str.contains` you will also have to 'build' your regex string by joining each values with `|` - the regex 'OR' operator.

**note**

A gotcha here - as you discovered - is that building the regex pattern this way will require you to escape any special regex characters in your lists. Example - you have '`:)`' in your compliments list. This will need to become '`\:\)`'

```
d = {'class1': class1,
     'class2': class2,
     'class3': class3,
     'class4': class4}

for name, values in d.items():
    # Create a regex string joining all the values in the list with the regex OR '|'
    pat = '|'.join(values)
    df.loc[df['text'].str.contains(pat), 'class'] = name
```

#### Simplified example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '2nn',1: '2nn',2: '2nn',3: '2nn',4: '2nn',5: '2nn',6: '2nn',7: '2nn',8: '2nn',9: '2nn',10: '2nn',11: '2nn',12: '2nn'},
                    'x1': {0: 'TT',1: 'TT',2: 'TT',3: 'TT',4: 'TT',5: 'TT',6: 'TT',7: 'TT',8: 'TT',9: 'TT',10: 'TT',11: 'TT',12: 'TT'},
                    'text': {0: 'abc',1: 'abc',2: 'e',3: 'h',4: 'm',5: 'p',6: 'q',7: 'd',8: 's',9: 'j',10: 'h',11: 'o',12: 'z'},
                    'x2': {0: 'QQ',1: 'QQ',2: 'QQ',3: 'QQ',4: 'QQ',5: 'QQ',6: 'QQ',7: 'QQ',8: 'QQ',9: 'QQ',10: 'QQ',11: 'QQ',12: 'QQ'},
                    'num': {0: 1,1: 1,2: 1,3: 1,4: 1,5: 1,6: 1,7: 1,8: 1,9: 1,10: 1,11: 1,12: 1},
                    'x3': {0: 'TT',1: 'TT',2: 'TT',3: 'TT',4: 'TT',5: 'TT',6: 'TT',7: 'TT',8: 'TT',9: 'TT',10: 'TT',11: 'TT',12: 'TT'},
                    'class': {0: np.nan,1: np.nan,2: np.nan,3: np.nan,4: np.nan,5: np.nan,6: np.nan,7: np.nan,8: np.nan,9: np.nan,10: np.nan,11: np.nan,12: np.nan}})

class1 = list('abcde')
class2 = list('fghi')
class3 = list('jklmn')
class4 = list('opqrs')

d = {'class1': class1,
     'class2': class2,
     'class3': class3,
     'class4': class4}

for name, values in d.items():
    pat = '|'.join(values)
    df.loc[df['text'].str.contains(pat), 'class'] = name

print(df)
```

[out]

```
     id  x1 text  x2  num  x3   class
0   2nn  TT    a  QQ    1  TT  class1
1   2nn  TT    b  QQ    1  TT  class1
2   2nn  TT    e  QQ    1  TT  class1
3   2nn  TT    h  QQ    1  TT  class2
4   2nn  TT    m  QQ    1  TT  class3
5   2nn  TT    p  QQ    1  TT  class4
6   2nn  TT    q  QQ    1  TT  class4
7   2nn  TT    d  QQ    1  TT  class1
8   2nn  TT    s  QQ    1  TT  class4
9   2nn  TT    j  QQ    1  TT  class3
10  2nn  TT    h  QQ    1  TT  class2
11  2nn  TT    o  QQ    1  TT  class4
12  2nn  TT    z  QQ    1  TT     NaN
```

Comment: I tried that, but while it didn't print out an error, all my values in my 'class' column are still `nan`. Any ideas?

Comment: @tushariyer could you post the code you tried using the dictionary method to the question?

Comment: I have added it to my original post below my previous code

Comment: i tihnk i see the problem, I've updated my answer. could you try that?

Comment: I tried it, and was given the following error: `
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression

error: unbalanced parenthesis`

Comment: its because of the `':)'` in your list of compliments.... you'll need to change it to `\:\)` - this escapes them as they are special regex characters

Comment: YOU HERO IT WORKED